# "ExceptionInInitializerError" when querying Oracle DB from jar built with Ant, but it works fine in IDE

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ant, ojdbc

When I run my Java code in my IDE, it runs successfully. When I build a jar file and run it from the commandline, I receive a "java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError" on the line which performs the actual query. I suspect there's a problem with my Apache Ant build script, but I'm not certain.

Here is my extremely simplified code (yes, I know I'm not fully closing out the DB connection on failure, but this is something small I created just to get the simplest version of code I could that still exhibits the error):

```
package com.company.TestApp.TestProj;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Main {
    public Main() {
        super();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.run();
    }
    
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Starting");

        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            Connection db = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, schema, password);
            if (db.isValid(10)) {
                System.out.println("Connected");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Not connected");
                throw new Exception("Not connected");
            }
            
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM dual";
            
            Statement statement = db.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("Record");
            }
            
            rs.close();
            statement.close();
            
            
            db.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My extremely simplified Apache Ant build script is:

```
<project name="test" basedir="." default="main">

    <property name="src.dir"     value="src"/>

    <property name="build.dir"   value="build"/>
    <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    <property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>

    <property name="main-class"  value="com.company.TestApp.TestProj.Main"/>

    <property name="lib.dir"     value="../lib"/>

    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
    </path>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath"/>
    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
        <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${jar.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.class"/>
            </fileset>
            <zipfileset src="${lib.dir}/ojdbc7.jar">
                <include name="**/*.class"/>
            </zipfileset>
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="run" depends="jar">
        <java fork="true" classname="${main-class}">
            <classpath>
                <path refid="classpath"/>
                <path location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
            </classpath>
        </java>
    </target>

    <target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar"/>

    <target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>

</project>
```

My IDE is JDeveloper 12.1.3.0.0.
My JAVA_HOME and path are set to JDK1.8.0_291.
My Oracle DB is 19.13.0.0.0

When I run the program from my IDE, I get the expected results of:

```
Starting
Connected
Record
```

When I run the jar from the commandline with "java -jar test.jar" the output is:

```
Starting
Connected
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.configureRowData(OracleStatement.java:760)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.<init>(OracleStatement.java:696)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.<init>(T4CStatement.java:1152)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.allocateStatement(T4CDriverExtension.java:46)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.createStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:3914)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.createStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:3874)
        at com.company.TestApp.TestProj.Main.run(Main.java:34)
        at com.company.TestApp.TestProj.Main.main(Main.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DynamicByteArray$1.run(DynamicByteArray.java:540)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DynamicByteArray.<clinit>(DynamicByteArray.java:535)
        ... 8 more
```

I am running Java JDK1.8.0_291, but I've tried it on other machines with different versions of Java and receive the same error. I'm using the ojdbc7.jar that came with JDeveloper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your fat JAR to run using `java -jar test.jar`, you need to make a small change to your Ant script.

Change this:

```xml
<zipfileset src="${lib.dir}/ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar">
    <include name="**/*.class"/>
</zipfileset>
```

to this:

```xml
<zipfileset src="${lib.dir}/ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar">
    <include name="**/*.*"/>
</zipfileset>
```

The reason: There are more than just `.class` files in the Oracle JDBC JAR.

There are also (for example) properties files such as

```
defaultConnectionProperties.properties
```

...and other files.

I don't know which *specific* missing file was the root cause of your exception. I just performed a build to include everything.

---

**Digression:**

You may already know the following - but for future visitors to this question...

It's worth noting also that the JDBC file contains a file called `java.sql.Driver` in `META-INF/services` - and that file contains the name of the Oracle driver class:

```
oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

Normally, this is used to automatically load the Oracle JDBC driver - so you don't need the following line of code:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
```

However that works by scanning the library JAR files - and since you no longer have the Oracle JAR file inside your application "fat" jar, you still *do* need the above line of code.

This is one of those relatively rare cases where that line is still needed, these days, to avoid a `No suitable driver found` exception.

Comment: Thank you! Not only did you help me to fix my issue, you explained to me why I was encountering to it, and why the fix works!

Answer (score 1):

A co-worker was able to get it working by manually specifying the classpath:

```
java -cp ..\..\..\lib\ojdbc7.jar;test.jar com.company.TestApp.TestProj.Main
```

I don't understand why this is needed, but I suspect I'm not properly including the ojdbc jar file in my ant script. If anyone can explain to me the way to fix this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Suggestion: If you are going to place the JDBC JAR on the classpath, like you do here, then I think you should use a "thin" version of your own JAR (the one containing _only_ your application code). Otherwise, you will have all of the Oracle class files included twice on the class path: Once in the Oracle JAR file and again in your "fat" JAR file.